# I want to get the n from this equation $y=1-(1-x)^n$ using $\ln$.

Tags: probability

This is my solution:

$$y = 1 - (1 - x)^n$$
$$y - 1 = - (1 - x)^n$$
$$\ln (y - 1) = - \ln (1 - x)^n$$
$$\ln (y - 1) = - n \ln (1 - x)$$
$$\frac{\ln (y - 1)}{\ln (1 - x)} = - n$$

But when I input values of $y = 0.2827$, it yields an invalid input because it is $\ln$.

Plugging the values of $x = 0.0643$ and $n = 5$ in the original equation.
$$y = 1 - (1 - 0.0643)^5$$
$$y = 0.2827$$

But it will yield an error when I plug the same values to the $\ln$ equation.

This formula is for probability, stacking chances for $n$ times. I don't know what it's called in mathematics.

Comment: In title, you have $x$. Where did it go ?

Comment: It isn't true that $\ln(-a)=-\ln(a)$  The third line is wrong.

Comment: wait i messed up.

Comment: @saulspatz ohhhhhwwwwwwww. i see. thanks.

Comment: Negate both sides of line three before taking a log.

Comment: @DavidP thanks.

Comment: I did an edit .... please check if it is ok... (just wanted to make it look more mathematical)

Comment: this is the correct answer: n = ln(1-y)/ln(1-x). yes! thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici sorry, I made a mistake in copying my equation. i edit the x to y already.